# Translate ANTLR grammar into XText grammar: how to remove syntactic predicates

Tags: antlr, grammar, xtext

I'm new to both Xtext and ANTLR.

I need to translate an ANTLR (.g) grammar into an XTEXT (.xtext) grammar. In the ANTLR grammar there are syntactic predicates which are not supported by Xtext.

Is there a way to remove/translate these predicates?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The ANTLR grammar which I'm trying to translate can be found here:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2009, Google Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
 * met:
 *
 *     * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 * notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *     * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
 * copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer
 * in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
 * distribution.
 *     * Neither the name of Google Inc. nor the names of its
 * contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
 * this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

// This file contains the ANTLR grammar for parsing GLSL ES into an Abstract
// Syntax Tree (AST).

grammar GLSL_ES;

options {
    language = Java;
}

@lexer::header  { package glsl_es; }
@parser::header { package glsl_es; }

/* Main entry point */
translation_unit
  : ( external_declaration )* EOF
  ;

variable_identifier
  : IDENTIFIER
  ;

primary_expression
  : INTCONSTANT
  | FLOATCONSTANT
  | BOOLCONSTANT
  | variable_identifier
  | LEFT_PAREN expression RIGHT_PAREN
  ;

postfix_expression
  : primary_expression_or_function_call
    ( LEFT_BRACKET integer_expression RIGHT_BRACKET
      | DOT field_selection
      | INC_OP
      | DEC_OP
    )*
  ;

primary_expression_or_function_call
  : ( INTCONSTANT ) => primary_expression
  | ( FLOATCONSTANT ) => primary_expression
  | ( BOOLCONSTANT ) => primary_expression
  | ( LEFT_PAREN ) => primary_expression
  | ( function_call_header ) => function_call
  | primary_expression
  ;

integer_expression
  : expression
  ;

function_call
  : function_call_generic
  ;

function_call_generic
  : function_call_header
    (
        (VOID)?
      | assignment_expression (COMMA assignment_expression)*
    )
    RIGHT_PAREN
  ;

function_call_header
  : function_identifier LEFT_PAREN
  ;

// NOTE: change compared to GLSL ES grammar, because constructor_identifier
// has IDENTIFIER (=TYPE_NAME) as one of its arms.
function_identifier
  : constructor_identifier
//  | IDENTIFIER
  ;

// Grammar Note: Constructors look like functions, but lexical analysis recognized most of them as 
// keywords.
//
// TODO(kbr): do we need to register declared struct types in a dictionary
// and look them up in order to be able to handle the TYPE_NAME constructor
// identifier type?

constructor_identifier
  : FLOAT
  | INT
  | BOOL
  | VEC2
  | VEC3
  | VEC4
  | BVEC2
  | BVEC3
  | BVEC4
  | IVEC2
  | IVEC3
  | IVEC4
  | MAT2
  | MAT3
  | MAT4
//  | TYPE_NAME
  | IDENTIFIER
  ;

unary_expression
  : (INC_OP | DEC_OP | unary_operator)* postfix_expression
  ;

// Grammar Note:  No traditional style type casts. 

unary_operator
  : PLUS
  | DASH
  | BANG
//| TILDE   // reserved
  ;

// Grammar Note:  No '*' or '&' unary ops.  Pointers are not supported. 

multiplicative_expression
  : unary_expression ((STAR | SLASH) unary_expression)*
//| multiplicative_expression PERCENT unary_expression   // reserved
  ;

additive_expression
  : multiplicative_expression ((PLUS | DASH) multiplicative_expression)*
  ;

shift_expression
  : additive_expression
//| shift_expression LEFT_OP additive_expression         // reserved
//| shift_expression RIGHT_OP additive_expression        // reserved
  ;

relational_expression
  : shift_expression ((LEFT_ANGLE | RIGHT_ANGLE | LE_OP | GE_OP) shift_expression)*
  ;

equality_expression
  : relational_expression ((EQ_OP | NE_OP) relational_expression)*
  ;

and_expression
  : equality_expression
//| and_expression AMPERSAND equality_expression         // reserved
  ;

exclusive_or_expression
  : and_expression
//| exclusive_or_expression CARET and_expression         // reserved
  ;

inclusive_or_expression
  : exclusive_or_expression
//| inclusive_or_expression VERTICAL_BAR exclusive_or_expression  // reserved
  ;

logical_and_expression
  : inclusive_or_expression (AND_OP inclusive_or_expression)*
  ;

logical_xor_expression
  : logical_and_expression (XOR_OP logical_and_expression)*
  ;

logical_or_expression
  : logical_xor_expression (OR_OP logical_xor_expression)*
  ;

conditional_expression
  : logical_or_expression (QUESTION expression COLON assignment_expression)?
  ;

assignment_expression
  : (unary_expression assignment_operator) => unary_expression assignment_operator assignment_expression
  | conditional_expression
  ;

assignment_operator
  : EQUAL
  | MUL_ASSIGN
  | DIV_ASSIGN
//| MOD_ASSIGN   // reserved
  | ADD_ASSIGN
  | SUB_ASSIGN
//| LEFT_ASSIGN  // reserved
//| RIGHT_ASSIGN // reserved
//| AND_ASSIGN   // reserved
//| XOR_ASSIGN   // reserved
//| OR_ASSIGN    // reserved
  ;

expression
  : assignment_expression (COMMA assignment_expression)*
  ;

constant_expression
  : conditional_expression
  ;

declaration
  : (function_header) => function_prototype SEMICOLON
  | init_declarator_list SEMICOLON
  | PRECISION precision_qualifier type_specifier_no_prec SEMICOLON
  ;

function_prototype
  : function_declarator RIGHT_PAREN
  ;

function_declarator
  : function_header (parameter_declaration (COMMA parameter_declaration)* )?
  ;

function_header
  : fully_specified_type IDENTIFIER LEFT_PAREN
  ;

parameter_declaration
  : (type_qualifier)? (parameter_qualifier)?
    ( type_specifier
      // parameter_declarator
      (IDENTIFIER)?
      // parameter_type_specifier
      (LEFT_BRACKET constant_expression RIGHT_BRACKET)?
    )
  ;

// NOTE: this originally had "empty" as one of the arms in the grammar

parameter_qualifier
  : IN
  | OUT
  | INOUT
  ;

init_declarator_list
  : single_declaration (init_declarator_list_1)*
  ;

init_declarator_list_1
  : COMMA IDENTIFIER (init_declarator_list_2)?
  ;

init_declarator_list_2
  : LEFT_BRACKET constant_expression RIGHT_BRACKET
  | EQUAL initializer
  ;

single_declaration
  : fully_specified_type
    ( IDENTIFIER
      (   LEFT_BRACKET constant_expression RIGHT_BRACKET
        | EQUAL initializer
      ) ?
    ) ?
  | INVARIANT IDENTIFIER   // Vertex only.
  ;

// Grammar Note:  No 'enum', or 'typedef'. 

fully_specified_type
  : type_specifier
  | type_qualifier type_specifier
  ;

type_qualifier
  : CONST
  | ATTRIBUTE   // Vertex only.
  | VARYING
  | INVARIANT VARYING
  | UNIFORM
  ;

type_specifier
  : type_specifier_no_prec
  | precision_qualifier type_specifier_no_prec
  ;

type_specifier_no_prec
  : VOID
  | FLOAT
  | INT
  | BOOL
  | VEC2
  | VEC3
  | VEC4
  | BVEC2
  | BVEC3
  | BVEC4
  | IVEC2
  | IVEC3
  | IVEC4
  | MAT2
  | MAT3
  | MAT4
  | SAMPLER2D
  | SAMPLERCUBE
  | struct_specifier
//  | TYPE_NAME
  | IDENTIFIER
  ;

precision_qualifier
  : HIGH_PRECISION
  | MEDIUM_PRECISION
  | LOW_PRECISION
  ;

struct_specifier
  : STRUCT (IDENTIFIER)? LEFT_BRACE struct_declaration_list RIGHT_BRACE
  ;

struct_declaration_list
  : (struct_declaration)+
  ;

struct_declaration
  : type_specifier struct_declarator_list SEMICOLON
  ;

struct_declarator_list
  : struct_declarator (COMMA struct_declarator)*
  ;

struct_declarator
  : IDENTIFIER (LEFT_BRACKET constant_expression RIGHT_BRACKET)?
  ;

initializer
  : assignment_expression
  ;

declaration_statement
  : declaration
  ;

statement_no_new_scope
  : compound_statement_with_scope
  | simple_statement
  ;

simple_statement
options { backtrack=true; }
  : declaration_statement
  | expression_statement
  | selection_statement
  | iteration_statement
  | jump_statement
  ;

compound_statement_with_scope
  : LEFT_BRACE (statement_list)? RIGHT_BRACE
  ;

statement_with_scope
  : compound_statement_no_new_scope
  | simple_statement
  ;

compound_statement_no_new_scope
  : LEFT_BRACE (statement_list)? RIGHT_BRACE
  ;

statement_list
  : (statement_no_new_scope)+
  ;

expression_statement
  : (expression)? SEMICOLON
  ;

selection_statement
options { backtrack=true; }
  : IF LEFT_PAREN expression RIGHT_PAREN statement_with_scope ELSE statement_with_scope
  | IF LEFT_PAREN expression RIGHT_PAREN statement_with_scope
  ;

condition
  : expression
  | fully_specified_type IDENTIFIER EQUAL initializer
  ;

iteration_statement
  : WHILE LEFT_PAREN condition RIGHT_PAREN statement_no_new_scope
  | DO statement_with_scope WHILE LEFT_PAREN expression RIGHT_PAREN SEMICOLON
  | FOR LEFT_PAREN for_init_statement for_rest_statement RIGHT_PAREN statement_no_new_scope
  ;

for_init_statement
options { backtrack=true; }
  : expression_statement
  | declaration_statement
  ;

for_rest_statement
  : (condition)? SEMICOLON (expression)?
  ;

jump_statement
  : CONTINUE SEMICOLON
  | BREAK SEMICOLON
  | RETURN (expression)? SEMICOLON
  | DISCARD SEMICOLON   // Fragment shader only.
  ;

external_declaration
  : (function_header) => function_definition
  | declaration
  ;

function_definition
  : function_prototype compound_statement_no_new_scope
  ;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Keywords

ATTRIBUTE        : 'attribute';
BOOL             : 'bool';
BREAK            : 'break';
BVEC2            : 'bvec2';
BVEC3            : 'bvec3';
BVEC4            : 'bvec4';
CONST            : 'const';
CONTINUE         : 'continue';
DISCARD          : 'discard';
DO               : 'do';
ELSE             : 'else';
FALSE            : 'false';
FLOAT            : 'float';
FOR              : 'for';
HIGH_PRECISION   : 'highp';
IF               : 'if';
IN               : 'in';
INOUT            : 'inout';
INT              : 'int';
INVARIANT        : 'invariant';
IVEC2            : 'ivec2';
IVEC3            : 'ivec3';
IVEC4            : 'ivec4';
LOW_PRECISION    : 'lowp';
MAT2             : 'mat2';
MAT3             : 'mat3';
MAT4             : 'mat4';
MEDIUM_PRECISION : 'mediump';
OUT              : 'out';
PRECISION        : 'precision';
RETURN           : 'return';
SAMPLER2D        : 'sampler2D';
SAMPLERCUBE      : 'samplerCube';
STRUCT           : 'struct'; 
TRUE             : 'true';
UNIFORM          : 'uniform';
VARYING          : 'varying';
VEC2             : 'vec2';
VEC3             : 'vec3';
VEC4             : 'vec4';
VOID             : 'void';
WHILE            : 'while';

IDENTIFIER
  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*
  ;

/*
// TODO(kbr): it isn't clear whether we need to support the TYPE_NAME
// token type; that may only be needed if typedef is supported
TYPE_NAME
  : IDENTIFIER
  ;
*/

// NOTE difference in handling of leading minus sign compared to HLSL
// grammar

fragment EXPONENT_PART : ('e'|'E') (PLUS | DASH)? ('0'..'9')+ ;

FLOATCONSTANT
  : ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* (EXPONENT_PART)?
  | '.' ('0'..'9')+ (EXPONENT_PART)?
  ;

fragment DECIMAL_CONSTANT
  : ('1'..'9')('0'..'9')*
  ;

fragment OCTAL_CONSTANT
  : '0' ('0'..'7')*
  ;

fragment HEXADECIMAL_CONSTANT
  : '0' ('x'|'X') HEXDIGIT+
  ;

fragment HEXDIGIT
  : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F')
  ;

INTCONSTANT
  : DECIMAL_CONSTANT
  | OCTAL_CONSTANT
  | HEXADECIMAL_CONSTANT
  ;

fragment BOOLCONSTANT
  : TRUE
  | FALSE
  ;

// TODO(kbr): this needs much more work
field_selection
  : IDENTIFIER
  ;

//LEFT_OP  : '<<';      - reserved
//RIGHT_OP : '>>';      - reserved

INC_OP           : '++';
DEC_OP           : '--';
LE_OP            : '<=';
GE_OP            : '>=';
EQ_OP            : '==';
NE_OP            : '!=';

AND_OP           : '&&';
OR_OP            : '||';
XOR_OP           : '^^';
MUL_ASSIGN       : '*=';
DIV_ASSIGN       : '/=';
ADD_ASSIGN       : '+=';
MOD_ASSIGN       : '%=';
// LEFT_ASSIGN   : '<<=';  - reserved
// RIGHT_ASSIGN  : '>>=';  - reserved
// AND_ASSIGN    : '&=';   - reserved
// XOR_ASSIGN    : '^=';   - reserved
// OR_ASSIGN     : '|=';   - reserved
SUB_ASSIGN       : '-=';

LEFT_PAREN       : '(';
RIGHT_PAREN      : ')';
LEFT_BRACKET     : '[';
RIGHT_BRACKET    : ']';
LEFT_BRACE       : '{';
RIGHT_BRACE      : '}';
DOT              : '.';

COMMA            : ',';
COLON            : ':';
EQUAL            : '=';
SEMICOLON        : ';';
BANG             : '!';
DASH             : '-';
TILDE            : '~';
PLUS             : '+';
STAR             : '*';
SLASH            : '/';
PERCENT          : '%';

LEFT_ANGLE       : '<';
RIGHT_ANGLE      : '>';
VERTICAL_BAR     : '|';
CARET            : '^';
AMPERSAND        : '&';
QUESTION         : '?';

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// skipped elements

WHITESPACE
  : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\f' | '\r' | '\n' )
  { $channel = HIDDEN; }
  ;

COMMENT
  : '//' (~('\n'|'\r'))*
  { $channel = HIDDEN; }
  ;

MULTILINE_COMMENT
  : '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/'
  { $channel = HIDDEN; }
  ;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Keywords reserved for future use

//RESERVED_KEYWORDS
//  : 'asm'
//  | 'cast'
//  | 'class'
//  | 'default'
//  | 'double'
//  | 'dvec2'
//  | 'dvec3'
//  | 'dvec4'
//  | 'enum'
//  | 'extern'
//  | 'external'
//  | 'fixed'
//  | 'flat'
//  | 'fvec2'
//  | 'fvec3'
//  | 'fvec4'
//  | 'goto'
//  | 'half'
//  | 'hvec2'
//  | 'hvec3'
//  | 'hvec4'
//  | 'inline'
//  | 'input'
//  | 'interface'
//  | 'long'
//  | 'namespace'
//  | 'noinline'
//  | 'output'
//  | 'packed'
//  | 'public'
//  | 'sampler1D'
//  | 'sampler1DShadow'
//  | 'sampler2DRect'
//  | 'sampler2DRectShadow'
//  | 'sampler2DShadow'
//  | 'sampler3D'
//  | 'sampler3DRect'
//  | 'short'
//  | 'sizeof'
//  | 'static'
//  | 'superp'
//  | 'switch'
//  | 'template'
//  | 'this'
//  | 'typedef'
//  | 'union'
//  | 'unsigned'
//  | 'using'
//  | 'volatile'
//  ;
```

Comment: thanks a lot..I posted a link to the ANTLR grammar..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try to translate the grammar directly by removing all syntactic predicates and enabling backtracking in Xtext. If that works, I'd try to eliminate backtracking by reviewing all the problems that Antlr finds. Your grammar looks pretty much like backtracking is not necessary if you apply certain best practices like Xtext's Actions to eliminate left recursion. Some of the usage patterns that you applied in your Antlr grammar will not be allowed in Xtext so I bet that most syntactic predicates will not be necessary any more as soon as so transformed the syntax to an Xtext compliant version.

E.g.

```
primary_expression_or_function_call
  : ( INTCONSTANT ) => primary_expression
  | ( FLOATCONSTANT ) => primary_expression
  | ( BOOLCONSTANT ) => primary_expression
  | ( LEFT_PAREN ) => primary_expression
  | ( function_call_header ) => function_call
  | primary_expression
  ;
```

is effectively something like:

```
  PrimaryExpression:
    IntValue | FloatValue | BooleanValue | Parens | FunctionCall;
```

with

```
  IntValue: value=INTCONSTANT;
  ..
  Parens: '(' Expression ')';
  FunctionCall: function=[Function] '(' 
    (arguments+=Expression (',' arguments+=Expression)*)?
  ')'
```

and so on. Have a look at the docs for details.