# Negating inside lexer- and parser rules

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlr3, parser-generator

How can the negation meta-character, `~`, be used in ANTLR's lexer- and parser rules?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Negating can occur inside [lexer and parser rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297770/practical-difference-between-parser-rules-and-lexer-rules-in-antlr).

Inside lexer rules you can negate characters, and inside parser rules you can negate tokens (lexer rules). But both lexer- and parser rules can only negate either single characters, or single tokens, respectively.

A couple of examples:

## lexer rules

To match one or more characters except lowercase ascii letters, you can do:

```
NO_LOWERCASE : ~('a'..'z')+ ;
```

*(the negation-meta-char, `~`, has a higher precedence than the `+`, so the rule above equals `(~('a'..'z'))+`)*

Note that `'a'..'z'` matches a single character (and can therefor be negated), but the following rule is invalid:

```
ANY_EXCEPT_AB : ~('ab') ;
```

Because `'ab'` (obviously) matches 2 characters, it cannot be negated. To match a token that consists of 2 character, but not `'ab'`, you'd have to do the following:

```
ANY_EXCEPT_AB 
  :  'a' ~'b' // any two chars starting with 'a' followed by any other than 'b'
  |  ~'a' .   // other than 'a' followed by any char
  ;
```

## parser rules

Inside parser rules, `~` negates a certain token, or more than one token. For example, you have the following tokens defined:

```
A : 'A';
B : 'B';
C : 'C';
D : 'D';
E : 'E';
```

If you now want to match any token except the `A`, you do:

```
p : ~A ;
```

And if you want to match any token except `B` and `D`, you can do:

```
p : ~(B | D) ;
```

However, if you want to match any two tokens other than `A` followed by `B`, you ***cannot*** do:

```
p : ~(A B) ;
```

Just as with lexer rules, you cannot negate more than a single token. To accomplish the above, you need to do:

```
P
  :  A ~B
  |  ~A .
  ;
```

Note that the `.` (DOT) char in a parser rules does ***not*** match any character as it does inside lexer rules. Inside parser rules, it matches any token (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D` or `E`, in this case).

Note that you cannot negate parser rules. The following is illegal:

```
p : ~a ;
a : A  ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was not aware that the `~` operator would apply to tokens when occurring in a parser rule.

Comment: @Gunther, no problem. I often mention it briefly in my answers, so from now on I can link to this Q&A. W.r.t. your converter, perhaps you're already using it, but perhaps not: the `org.antlr.tool.Strip` class removes all custom code from ANTLR grammar files which may make your life easier when parsing ANTLR grammars.