# Antlr: ignore keywords in specific context

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3, ll-grammar

I'm constructing an English-like domain specific language with ANTLR. Its keywords are context-sensitive. (I know it sounds dirty, but it makes a lot of sense for the non-programmer target users.) For example, the usual logical operators such as `or` and `not` are to be treated as identifiers when surrounded in brackets, [like this and this]. My current approach looks like this:

```
bracketedStatement
    : '[' bracketedWord+ ']'
    ;

bracketedWord
    :   (~(']')+
    ;
```

This, when combined with lexical definitions such as the following:

```
AND: 'and' ;
OR: 'or' ;
```

Produces the warning`"Decision can match input such as "{AND..PROCESS, RPAREN..'with'}" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2"`.  I'm clearly creating ambiguity for ANTLR, but I don't know how to resolve it. How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you show a more complete example? In ANTLR, the order of the rules is important, and may lead to ambiguity.

Comment: `~(']')` inside a parser rule does not do what you think it does. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284919/negating-inside-lexer-and-parser-rules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negating inside lexer- and parser rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284919/negating-inside-lexer-and-parser-rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this, check out [this stack overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284919/negating-inside-lexer-and-parser-rules) It clarifies how to use the negation symbol correctly.