# Parsing list format in MarkDown file use Antlr4

Tags: markdown, antlr4

I'm try to parse MarkDown text with Antlr4. to make it easy I get to parse `list` view first.
And I found a webpage about it.
 http://www.cforcoding.com/2010/01/markdown-and-introduction-to-parsing.html

The grammer in that webpage seems ok to me, I change it to fit  Antlr4 format like this:

```
grammar MarkDown;

listItem    : ORDERED inline NEWLINE
        | UNORDERED inline NEWLINE
        ;
inline      : (~ NEWLINE)+ ;
ORDERED     : DIGIT+ '.' (' ' | '\t')+ ;
UNORDERED   : ('*' | '-' | '+') (' ' | '\t')+ ;
DIGIT       : [0-9]+ ;

NEWLINE     : '\r'? '\n' ;
```

example file

```
1. abc
2. kljjkj
3. tree4545
```

But it not works, error messages below

```
line 1:3 token recognition error at: 'a'
line 1:4 token recognition error at: 'b'
line 1:5 token recognition error at: 'c'
line 1:6 extraneous input '\r\n' expecting {ORDERED, UNORDERED, DIGIT}
line 2:3 token recognition error at: 'k'
line 2:4 token recognition error at: 'l'
line 2:5 token recognition error at: 'j'
line 2:6 token recognition error at: 'j'
line 2:7 token recognition error at: 'k'
line 2:8 token recognition error at: 'j'
(listItem 1.  (inline \r\n 2. ) \r\n)
```

Could you help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Inside a parser rule, the `~` negates tokens, not characters. So `inline` will try to match any tokens except `NEWLINE`, which is either `ORDERED`, `UNORDERED` or `DIGIT`.

ANTLR complains about the input `"abc"`, `"kljjkj"`, ... because no lexer rule match these chars.

Although the following Q&A is about ANTLR3, the same rules apply to ANTLR4: [Negating inside lexer- and parser rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284919/negating-inside-lexer-and-parser-rules)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you give an directly suggestion of fixing it?
See if I can understand easily.