# ANTLR4: how to create a rule for "not after"

Tags: antlr

I'm trying to create a rule to catch codas in syllables. A coda is some consonant which may or may not follow a nucleus and may never follow an onset; so my rule for `coda` should have `consonant` after a negation of `onset`. Assuming that negation is done in ANTLR with `~`, I'm struggling to get it work. Here's my original attempt:

```
syllable
  : onset? nucleus coda?
  ;
coda
  : ~onset consonant
  ;
```

The grammar file had been fine until I inserted `~`, now it's reutrning me the error message *"no viable alternative at input '~onset'"*. Then I read somewhere that `~` negates all on its right hand side, so I changed it to:

```
coda
  : ~onset
    consonant
  ;
```

The problem persists. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of ideas.

Bart is correct that you can't use negation of a rule match in your grammar definition.

A coupe of thoughts to toss out:  (I can't quite make enough of the detail of you grammar out to be able to put an example together).

As I see it, there are two possibilities for this being "invalid":

---

1 - if you encounter this construct, it's an error, period.

If this is the case then you can simply change the rule to:

```
bad_coda
  : onset consonant;
coda
  : consonant;
```

And then, in a Listener or Visitor, if you encounter a `bad_coda` context, you can throw your own error message.

In this way you're using ANTLR as a "Recognizer" (actually the name of one of the superclasses of Parser for a reason), that "recognizes" this error situation.

Lesson:  You're not limited to putting *ONLY* rules for what is valid in your grammar.

---

2 - If you encounter this sequence of tokens, you want to not recognize it as a coda, but perhaps there is another rule that *would* match (so you just need this rule to *fail* so that another might be attempted).  In this case, the previous approach would not work, as `bad_coda` would match.

In that case, you might get away with making `onset` optional, and writing a semantic predicate that rejects the rule if the `onset` is actually present.

```
coda:
  : onset? { /* predicate that rejects if onset is present */} consonant
```

(NOTE: not having enough to work with here, I haven't tried this out, but it may be worth a shot.)

Comment: Hehe, you can safely remove the "obviously" from your answer @Mike :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside parser rules, you can only negate tokens, not other parser rules.

See: [Negating inside lexer- and parser rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284919/negating-inside-lexer-and-parser-rules)