# How to make an ANTLR grammar that matches strings both inside and outside a delimiter?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

This grammar for ANTLR4 should break a document up into two types of substring: wiki and nowiki.

```
grammar NoWikiText;

nowiki: '<nowiki>' ~'</nowiki>'* '</nowiki>';
wiki: ~'<nowiki>'+;
document: (wiki | nowiki)*;
```

Here's the input:

```
<nowiki>2</nowiki>4<nowiki></nowiki>
```

I get two matches for nowiki. But the text "4", which should match wiki, is ignored. Why?

EDIT:

This seems to work:

```
grammar NoWikiText;

P1: '<nowiki>';
P2: '</nowiki>';
NP: .;

nowiki: P1 NP* P2;
wiki: NP+;
document: (wiki | nowiki)*;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the grammar you posted, only 2 tokens will be created: `<nowiki>` and `</nowiki>`. [The negations char works differently than you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284919/negating-inside-lexer-and-parser-rules): `~'</nowiki>'` means: "match any token other than `</nowiki>`" (so that would match the token `<nowiki>`). So for your input `<nowiki>2</nowiki>4<nowiki></nowiki>`, the `2` and `4` are not recognized as valid tokens.