# Is there a java grammar file for Xtext?

Tags: java, xtext

I want to create certain files from Java-source files (input: *.java files; output: something). Xtext seems like a good tool for this. Of course, you have to define the grammar (in this case: Java) first. But Xtext should be able to parse Java files and generate some files from them (if I write templates).

Somehow I can not image, that this has not been done before. I looked it up, but did not find anything. So the question is:

Is there a Xtext-grammar file, for Java (which defines the Java grammar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had the same issue. Since Xtext uses Antlr under the hood, I was
>   trying to find an Antlr Java grammar. I found this file from [Terence
>   Parr](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1152141644268/Java.g). I got about 1000 lines ...
>
> I took [this post](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8279790/convert-simple-antlr-grammar-to-xtext) into consideration and adjusted the grammar line
>   by line. I took me while Wink I wasn't able to adapt every statement,
>   so I just commented some of them out. I attached the grammar if
>   someone else is trying to build a DSL on top of Java. I don't think
>   that the grammar is completely right, it at least contains the issues
>   listed in the original grammar.

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/251746/

Answer (score 0):

Since Xtext uses Antlr under the hood try the follwing link: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java.

Comment: Xtext uses antlr3, so antlr4 grammars are completely useless. It also lacks several features that are needed (e.g.: semantic predicates). Porting a antlr3 grammar to Xtext is *not* as trivial as You seem to imply.

Answer (score 0):

Another option now is to use JBase (https://github.com/LorenzoBettini/jbase). JBase was created to support Java expressions in XText languages (see https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2972217) and can be incorporated with minor changes by extending JBase instead of XBase.